# Java / Scala math library with elliptic integrals and bessel functions?

Tags: java, scala, numeric, numerical

I am looking for a math library for scientific computing to use in Java / Scala. Especially I need complete elliptic integrals und modified Bessel functions. I would be nice if it is open source, but I guess I will have to take whatever is out there. A scipy (python lib for scientific computing) replacment would be great :-)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, the most widely used Java math libraries are:

- The [Apache Commons Math library](http://commons.apache.org/math/), and
- The [Colt project](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/) (developed by [CERN](http://public.web.cern.ch/public/))

You'll have to investigate their [respective](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/index.html) [APIs](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.1/index.html) though to determine if they provide exactly the functionality you require.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the GNU Scientific Library contains both elliptic integrals and Bessel functions of many kinds.  Unfortunately, good mathematics libraries are hard to come by; your best bet may be to wrap the GSL using JNI (or JNA if you can get it to work).

If you really must have pure Java/Scala functions, I guess you could translate the portions of the library you need.  It would be a lot of work, but it is GPLed code at least.