# Scipy-like functionality in Java / Scala?

Tags: java, scala, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I'm trying to port some Python code to Scala.  It makes heavy use of Numpy and Scipy.  While I've found a number of dense matrix / linear algebra libraries that will do as an adequate (but not superb) replacement for NumPy, I've not really found anything that provides the functionality I use in SciPy.  In particular, I'm looking for a libraries that support sparse partial eigendecompositions (like SciPy's wrapping of arpack), and then libraries for some simple things that SciPy provides (e.g. histograms).

Comment: Even though I'm not trying to suggest that this question is on the wrong forum; you might also try reposting at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ just because there are a lot of people who do grad work and research there; its likely a portion of them have familiarity with mathematical programming libraries.

Comment: Just curious: why have you decided to migrate from Python to Scala? I'm asking because I'm so far a Python person as well (amongst many other languages) and now actively learning Scala.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There have been a few similar questions already on this topic:

1. [Java/Scala library for algebra, mathematics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193781/java-scala-library-for-algebra-mathematics)
2. [Java / Scala math library with elliptic integrals and bessel functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764989/java-scala-math-library-with-elliptic-integrals-and-bessel-functions)
3. [Clojure or Scala for bioinformatics/biostatistics/medical research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250459/clojure-or-scala-for-bioinformatics-biostatistics-medical-research)

Also, http://code.google.com/p/scalalab/ looks interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Blatant opportunism: I'm the author of numsca, the numpy for scala.
Obviously the best in town.

Numsca lives here: https://github.com/botkop/numsca

Feedback appreciated.

Thank you.