# Scala equivalent to scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, r, scala, scipy

I'm trying to port code, originally in R, from Python to Scala.  The original R code used nloptr, an R interface to NLopt.  The python code uses [scipy.optimize.minimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/optimize.minimize-slsqp.html#optimize-minimize-slsqp).

I've found the [minimize function in breeze.optimize](http://www.scalanlp.org/api/breeze/index.html#breeze.optimize.package) thanks to another post I found on SO ([Scipy-like functionality in Java / Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612846/scipy-like-functionality-in-java-scala)), however I'm not sure how suitable of a replacement it is.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: I know that breeze.optimize doesn't directly have NLopt or SLSQP, but I was wondering about trying to use LBFGS.