# Problem/bug with list values reading from Spark dataframe during plotting spikes detection using find_peaks from SciPy

Tags: python, pyspark, scipy, typeerror, peak-detection

Let's say I have following pandas dataframe contains `value` over time or `date`:

```py
import pandas as pd

pdf = pd.DataFrame(data={'date':['2020-10-16','2020-10-17','2020-10-18','2020-10-19','2020-10-20','2020-10-21','2020-10-22','2020-10-23','2020-10-24','2020-10-25','2020-10-26','2020-10-27','2020-10-28','2020-10-29','2020-10-30','2020-10-31','2020-11-01','2020-11-02','2020-11-03','2020-11-04','2020-11-05','2020-11-06','2020-11-07','2020-11-08','2020-11-09','2020-11-10','2020-11-11','2020-11-12','2020-11-13','2020-11-14','2020-11-15'],
                        'value':[161967, 161270, 148508, 152442, 157504, 157118, 155674, 134522, 213384, 163242, 217415, 221502, 146267, 143621, 145875, 139488, 104466, 94825, 143686, 151952, 161074, 161417, 135042, 148768, 131428, 127816, 151905, 180498, 177899, 193950, 12]})
pdf
```

or I have following Spark dataframe with similar data:

```py
import pyspark.sql.types
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType, TimestampType, DateType

dict  = [ ('2020-10-16', 161967),
          ('2020-10-17', 161270),
          ('2020-10-18', 148508),
          ('2020-10-19', 152442),
          ('2020-10-20', 157504),
          ('2020-10-21', 157118),
          ('2020-10-22', 155674),
          ('2020-10-23', 134522),
          ('2020-10-24', 213384),
          ('2020-10-25', 163242),
          ('2020-10-26', 217415),
          ('2020-10-27', 221502),
          ('2020-10-28', 146267),
          ('2020-10-29', 143621),
          ('2020-10-30', 145875),
          ('2020-10-31', 139488),
          ('2020-11-01', 104466),
          ('2020-11-02', 94825),
          ('2020-11-03', 143686),
          ('2020-11-04', 151952),
          ('2020-11-05', 161074),
          ('2020-11-06', 161417),
          ('2020-11-07', 135042),
          ('2020-11-08', 148768),
          ('2020-11-09', 131428),
          ('2020-11-10', 127816),
          ('2020-11-11', 151905),
          ('2020-11-12', 180498),
          ('2020-11-13', 177899),
          ('2020-11-14', 193950),
          ('2020-11-15', 12),

  ]

schema = StructType([ 
    StructField("date",        StringType(),    True), \
    StructField("value",       IntegerType(),   True), \
  ])
 
#create a Spark dataframe
sc= SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=dict,schema=schema)
sdf.printSchema()
sdf.sort('date').show(truncate = False)
```

I inspired from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59263392/10452700) to detect peaks and valleys via below code:

```py
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Input signal from Pandas dataframe
t = pdf.date
x = pdf.value

# Set thresholds
# std calculated on 10-90 percentile data, without outliers is used for threshold
thresh_top    = np.median(x) + 1 * np.std(x)
thresh_bottom = np.median(x) - 1 * np.std(x)


# Find indices of peaks & of valleys (from inverting the signal)
peak_idx, _   = find_peaks(x,  height =  thresh_top)
valley_idx, _ = find_peaks(-x, height = -thresh_bottom)

# Plot signal
plt.figure(figsize=(14,12))
plt.plot(t, x   , color='b', label='data')
plt.scatter(t, x, s=10,c='b',label='value')

# Plot threshold
plt.plot([min(t), max(t)], [thresh_top, thresh_top],       '--',  color='r', label='peaks-threshold')
plt.plot([min(t), max(t)], [thresh_bottom, thresh_bottom], '--',  color='g', label='valleys-threshold')

# Plot peaks (red) and valleys (blue)
plt.plot(t[peak_idx],   x[peak_idx],   "x", color='r', label='peaks')
plt.plot(t[valley_idx], x[valley_idx], "x", color='g', label='valleys')


plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.ylabel('value')
plt.xlabel('timestamp')
plt.title(f'data over time')
plt.legend( loc='lower left')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

and it works and plot it successfully when I read data from Pandas dataframe `pdf` before creating Spark dataframe. once I created Spark dataframe `sdf` even if you run the same cell on notebook within reading and input signal from pandas `pdf` doesn't work anymore and gives following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-1c79b34272c5> in <module>()
     23 
     24 # Plot threshold
---> 25 plt.plot([min(t), max(t)], [thresh_top, thresh_top],       '--',  color='r', label='peaks-threshold')
     26 plt.plot([min(t), max(t)], [thresh_bottom, thresh_bottom], '--',  color='g', label='valleys-threshold')
     27 

2 frames
/content/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/column.py in _to_java_column(col)
     47             "{0} of type {1}. "
     48             "For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' "
---> 49             "function.".format(col, type(col)))
     50     return jcol
     51 

TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 0     2020-10-16
1     2020-10-17
2     2020-10-18
3     2020-10-19
4     2020-10-20
5     2020-10-21
6     2020-10-22
7     2020-10-23
8     2020-10-24
9     2020-10-25
10    2020-10-26
11    2020-10-27
12    2020-10-28
13    2020-10-29
14    2020-10-30
15    2020-10-31
16    2020-11-01
17    2020-11-02
18    2020-11-03
19    2020-11-04
20    2020-11-05
21    2020-11-06
22    2020-11-07
23    2020-11-08
24    2020-11-09
25    2020-11-10
26    2020-11-11
27    2020-11-12
28    2020-11-13
29    2020-11-14
30    2020-11-15
Name: date, dtype: object of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

when I try it directly to read data from spark dataframe using:

```py
# Input signal from Spark dataframe
t = [val.date  for val in sdf.select('date').collect()]
x = [val.value for val in sdf.select('value').collect()]
```

sadly the plotting code doesn't work and throw out following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-9cfede77d0fb> in <module>()
     31 # Find indices of peaks & of valleys (from inverting the signal)
     32 peak_idx, _   = find_peaks(x,  height =  thresh_top)
---> 33 valley_idx, _ = find_peaks(-x, height = -thresh_bottom)
     34 
     35 

TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'list'
```

I spent lots of time but I couldn't fixed this bug. I also open to other non-`find_peaks()` solutions to plot spike detection like this numpythonic [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50778453/10452700) if I can adapt to the code and apply on Spark dataframe. I have tried many things you could check in this google [Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13Fz__TUJSWpwVVTDVPRJeyvPsremKnfM?usp=sharing) and feel free to run/test/edit it for quick debugging.

Comment: I realized that also there are some issues to use SciPy libraries in Scala based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370759/using-python-scipy-from-spark-scala) but I'm not sure if it is the case in PySpark. Hopefully there is a non-SciPy solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not working with the same objects.

When you work with pandas and you get `x = pdf.value` you actually get `Series` object. This object can take `-` in front and it knows that it has to convert the values in it to negative.

But when you work with PySpark and you collect values, you get `list` object and if you put `-` in front you get error:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'list'
```

Which tells you that it doesn't know how to deal with it.

- So the first thing to do, instead of:

```
valley_idx, _ = find_peaks(-x, height=-thresh_bottom)
```

You have to convert values to negative, for example:

```
valley_idx, _ = find_peaks([-i for i in x], height=-thresh_bottom)
```

- Next, `find_peaks` will return `ndarray` which again cannot be used with `list` in:

```py
plt.plot(t[peak_idx], x[peak_idx], "x", color="r", label="peaks")
```

So you'll have to do it manually, for example:

```py
plt.plot(
        [t[i] for i in peak_idx],
        [x[i] for i in peak_idx],
        "x",
        color="r",
        label="peaks",
    )
```

I've reproduced your plot with the following code (+ calculating `median` and `std_dev` in PySpark as an example):

```py
# data is the same
# ...

# create a Spark dataframe
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
std_dev = sdf.select(F.stddev(F.col("value")).alias("std")).collect()[0]["std"]
median = (
    sdf.groupBy("value")
    .agg(F.expr("percentile_approx(value, 0.5)").alias("med"))
    .collect()[0]["med"]
)
thresh_top = median + 1 * std_dev
thresh_bottom = median - 1 * std_dev
t = sdf.select("date").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
x = sdf.select("value").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
peak_idx, _ = find_peaks(x, height=thresh_top)
valley_idx, _ = find_peaks([-i for i in x], height=-thresh_bottom)

plt.figure(figsize=(14, 12))
plt.plot(t, x, color="b", label="data")
plt.scatter(t, x, s=10, c="b", label="value")

# Plot threshold
plt.plot(
    [min(t), max(t)],
    [thresh_top, thresh_top],
    "--",
    color="r",
    label="peaks-threshold",
)
plt.plot(
    [min(t), max(t)],
    [thresh_bottom, thresh_bottom],
    "--",
    color="g",
    label="valleys-threshold",
)

# Plot peaks (red) and valleys (blue)
plt.plot(
    [t[i] for i in peak_idx],
    [x[i] for i in peak_idx],
    "x",
    color="r",
    label="peaks",
)
plt.plot(
    [t[i] for i in valley_idx],
    [x[i] for i in valley_idx],
    "x",
    color="g",
    label="valleys",
)

# ...
```

Comment: numpy array to list conversion is better using `tolist()` method: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried to reproduce plot using your solution but on [Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13Fz__TUJSWpwVVTDVPRJeyvPsremKnfM?usp=sharing) if you check it out, but I faced `TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: ['2020-10-16', ..., '2020-11-15'] of type <class 'list'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.` Would you run your solution on the Notebook to debug the issue completely?

Comment: I couldn't reach the plot and I already faced the current error when I tried to cast the `date` column before `collect()` using `.cast(DateType())` unsuccessfully and comment it in the last cell. The cell before the last cell in Colab Notebook is your Solution.

Comment: @Mario Please remove `from pyspark.sql.functions import *` from the top and try again, it clashes the namespace for functions `max`, `min`. Always use `from pyspark.sql import functions as F` and use `F.<function>` so you don't have similar problems.

Comment: Thanks to your tips, I just could fix and reproduce the plot but surprisingly the thresholds are not the same when I compared the plots out of pandas dataframe & plot out of Spark dataframe. You can see them on Notebook or this [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/fNwlGGF.png). I printed them on the legend at the left bottom of the plots nevertheless you can distinguish it on plots as well. I noticed that you didn't use NumPy in threshold calculations `np.median(x) + 1 * np.std(x)`. Is there any special reason?

Comment: Oh, interesting. Could you try again with `np.median(x) + 1 * np.std(x)` just use `x` from pyspark `collect`?
Nope, no special reason, you can use `numpy` if you want. Just wanted to show you different options.

Comment: Great, and many thanks for your contribution to fixing this issue; you made my day.